# Count the drop-downs

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to count the number of occurrence of the dropdowns that changes as soon as the dropdowns are changed for example
apple
oranges
apple
grape
apple
oranges
oranges
apple
oranges

4 apples, 4 oranges, 1 grape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onEdit() trigger only fires when a user makes a change.  So if your onEdit() function is targeting a range that has a validation then any trigger that occurs indicates a change.  So count them.  You could store the counts in another sheet or perhaps even in PropertiesService.  Depending upon how you target them you could store them in property keys that reflect their range.

Here's a simple example of an installable onEdit() that checks for changes in cells that have validation rule criterias of VALUE_IN_LIST or VALUE_IN_RANGE.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast('Got Trigger');
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  checkForValidations(e);
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem('Display Counts', 'displayScriptProperties')
  .addItem('Create Installable Trigger', 'createTrigger')
  .addItem('Remove All Properties','removeAllScriptProperties') 
  .addToUi();
}


function checkForValidations(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Checking');
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var row=e.range.rowStart;
  var col=e.range.columnStart;
  var vA=rg.getDataValidations();
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      var rule=vA[i][j];
      if(rule!=null) {
        var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
        if(criteria==SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST || criteria==SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) {
          var loc=Utilities.formatString('%s', sh.getRange(i+row,j+col).getA1Notation());
          e.source.toast(loc);//you can remove this
          if(ps.getProperty(loc)) {
            ps.setProperty(loc,parseInt(ps.getProperty(loc))+1);
          }else{
            ps.setProperty(loc,1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}

function displayScriptProperties() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lObj=ps.getProperties();
  var html="";
  for(var key in lObj) {
    html+='<br />' + key + ' = ' + lObj[key];
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Script Properties");
}

function createTrigger() {
  if(!isTrigger('onMyEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){//prevents multiple triggers from being created
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function removeAllScriptProperties() {
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Are you sure that you wish to delete ALL SCRIPT Properties?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO)
  if(resp==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    ps.deleteAllProperties();
  }
  return;
}
```